# NetLogo : Redeclaration of turtles-own

Tags: netlogo

I am a beginner with NetLogo and am having troubles declaring variables as attributes of a turtle. I want 2 variables to be properties of turtles but when I use turtles-own second time, it throws an error saying Redeclaration of turtles-own. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just list all turtle variables in one `turtles-own`, like so:

```
turtles-own [
  one-variable
  another-variable
]
```